# Filter datagridview that fill with IList

Tags: datagridview, filter, ilist

Load my resources with this code :

```
public IList LoadResources()
        {
            using (var proxy = new MetaDataServiceReference.MetaDataManagementServiceClient())
            {
                var errorList = new MetaDataServiceReference.ValidationError[] { };
                var result = (from p in proxy.ResourceLoadAll(ref errorList)
                              select new 
                            {
                                BookAuthorId = p.ResourceID,
                                BookAuthorTitle= p.BookTitle
                            }).ToList();
                return result;
            }            
        }
```

and fill my datagridview with this code :

```
private void LoadResources()
        {
            ContentPool Db = new ContentPool();
            IList Resources = Db.LoadResources();
            DgvResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource = Resources;
            DgvResourcesOrAuthors.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }
```

How can I filter my datagridview data in FilterTextBox text change ?

I use for example this code, but has error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) :

```
private void TxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (DgvResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("BookAuthorTitle = '{0}'", TxFilter.Text.Trim());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullReferenceException` because the `DataGridView.DataSource` is of type `IList` and you are typecasting as `DataTable`.

To achieve filtering with List data,

```
private void TxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList var = DgvResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource as IList;
    if(var != null)
    {
        IList filteredData = //iterate list and filter based on condition
        DgvResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource = filteredData;
    }
}
```

When filtering is removed, set the `DataSource` to the original list.

```
IList Resources = Db.LoadResources();
DgvResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource = Resources;
```

If you don't want to change the DataSource then use `DataTable` along with `BindingSource` then you can filter as mentioned in your post.

```
private void TxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (DgvResourcesOrAuthors.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("BookAuthorTitle = '{0}'", TxFilter.Text.Trim());
}
```